# Pivot table custom sub total

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

Is there any way to create a row in a pivot table that will contain subtotals of a specific subset of a row label. For instance if I had a row label named source that had the following values: A, B, G, H, #, ?. Can I create a row that subtotals the various efforts mailed based on whether the source is A, B, G, H but not include the counts for #, ?. The following is what I currently have and the bold section is what I would like added.

Source ----- Eff1 Mailed ------ Eff2 Mailed
A----------------         10--------------------            10
B-----------------            5----------------------            4
G-------------          148--------------------        140
H-------------          658--------------------        524
**TOTAL-----        821--------------------        678**
$------------          1247------------------         1056
?   --------------         52---------------------          47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, with a Calculated Item that sums A+B+G+H but frankly this may be easier by adding a flag to your source data for those entries and adding that flag as a ROW.

HOWEVER, select a ROW item (say `A`), PIVOTTABLE TOOLS > ANALYZE > Calculations - Fields, Items, & Sets, Calculated Item..., Name: as you wish, Formula:

```
 =SUM(A+B+G+H)
```

OK.

[image: SO29102387 example]

Comment: Unfortunately the values are not always the same for the source field. We may A, B, G, H one time and then have A, B, J, L,M,X the next time. Would a calculated item still work? I essentially just need to add the values for all sources that are not # or ?.

Comment: I must be having a road block in my mind or I am over-complicating things. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this since I have to be able to display the individual sources and numbers mailed as well as the total of all sources mailed excluding those with a value of # and ?. Since calculated items will not allow you to use references or arrays I don't see how it will work. I thought about trying to add a total column to my source data but then how would I calculate that through SQL?

Comment: No that does not seem to be doing the trick. The final table should list all of the individual sources with the quantity mailed for effort 1, effort 2 and so on. As well as a value under source that says total conversion which will be a sum of all the individual sources listed above it. Then it will include the individual quantities for sources # and ?.